# codeigniter load a model which has a constructor with a parameter

Tags: php, codeigniter

My model class:

```
<?php class Permissions extends CI_Model {

    private $userID   = '';
    private $permissions = '';

    function __construct($userID)
    {
        // Call the Model constructor
        parent::__construct();

        $this->userID = $userID;
        ....
    }
    function __construct()
    {.....}
?>
```

and I want to load this model with a parameter, apparently I could not do it.
Without a parameter I can load parameterless constructor by this way:

```
$this->load->model('Permissions');
```

My first question: is loading a model with a parameter nonsense?
Second one: if it is doable, how can I do that?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might need to tweak the loader class to create a method which copies the `model()` method but accept paramenters. Then you call `$this->load->modelnew('modelname',$param)`. Oh, and you need to create a MY_Model class that extends the CI_Model one too

Comment: probably you are right, but it is much more easier to call a init function after loading it. still thanks for attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a look at this forum thread: http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/115681/

But I can't see why would you want to give a userid as a parameter in a way for permission checking? Guessing you use sessions to save userdata, write the userid in the session and call this in the Model with $this->session->userdata('user_id').

Happy coding!

Comment: Please give the solution instead of linking to a solution. The link might become inaccessible over time, like it did for this one.

Answer (score 3):

you can instantiate the class it self, instead of loading it.

$permission = new Permission($param);

Answer (score 0):

You can do your customization in you model's function level. If you provide why do you extend the model, I can say whether it makes sense or not. If you want to create a  user specific rule, you had better to do it on a controller.

```
class Shop_m extends CI_Model {

 function getProductPriceInfo($cat,$id) {
        $this->db->where('shop_price.catid', $cat); 
                $this->db->where('shop_price.relid', $id); 
                $this->db->select('optional.title,optional.desc,shop_price.*');
                $this->db->join('optional', 'optional.id = shop_price.relid');
        $q = $this->db->get('shop_price');
        if($q->num_rows() > 0) {
            foreach ($q->result() as $row) {
                $data[] = $row;
            }
        return $data;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I will have different lvl of users with different permissions. I am taking this permissions from database so I have used Model. Using my model, I will check whether a user ie: list some products or edit some products. Still is it better to use a controller? (PS: I am newbie to codeigniter, and not professional to php.)

Comment: I would do it on controller level. Because all of the logic has better to be in your controllers. You can get data about permissions from a model, and check permissions on controller. I would create a helper or a library to check permissions. For example if you are creating a section which is member only, you can check that section's controller whether the user has permission to do it. Or if you want to check whether if a user has a permission to change some data, you had better to check the permissions on the controller which you update data. Shortly, make every rules on your controllers.

Comment: To be specific, when you are listing some products, user access a controller which gets data from model and loads data to views. So you can check whether the user has a permission to list products when s/he access that controller. If he has permission, get the data with model and load it to a view, else give error such as 'you dont have access to this section'.